# Using WFS layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: wfs, arcgis-pro

Is there a way to directly add a WFS layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Prior to ArcGIS Pro 2.0 the only way to use a WFS service is to convert it to a feature layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At ArcGIS Pro 2.0 (July 2017), native WFS-support was added, as explained at https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/06/27/arcgis-pro-2-0-has-been-released/

> Consume native OGC Web Feature Service (WFS) Services directly in
>   ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Do you know if it is only simple feature WFS, and which versions of the WFS standard that are supported?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up talking to ESRI's customer's support on the phone and they told me that there is a software limitation there and that the only way of using WFS services in ArcGIS Pro is to first export it in a feature layer (a shapefile, or in a FGDB).

You can't use the WFS service like a normal layer, even with their Interoperability extension.

I am dropping a link [here](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13012-using-a-web-feature-service-wfs-without-converting-it-to-a-feature-layer-arcgis-pro) in case you want to up-vote the idea of adding this functionality (ArcGIS Ideas portal)